# Support GB18030 character set

Tags: java, tomcat

How to provide support for GB18030 character set? My service gives a 403 while connecting to Virtual Machines (via RDP) that have these characters in the VM name. I believe for this I need to set the requestURI encoding to support these special characters? How do I do that? Should these be converted to and from UTF-8/16 or is there some other wat this can be achieved?

Comment: *Which* characters?